# Одновременный запуск одной формы в приложении

Tags: c#, многопоточность, таймер

Есть форма, которая делает api запрос через таймер. Мне нужно запустить несколько таких форм, чтобы они делали api запрос. Но при создании второй формы ничего не происходит. Как заставить работать их одновременно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 private void status_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(createForm));
        th2.Start();
    }

    public static void createForm()
    {
       new logForm("-1111111").ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Хоть бы одну строчку кода.

Comment: Добавил выше...

Comment: `Thread th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(createForm));` так делать нельзя. Граф.интерфейс работает только в одном потоке. И зачем вам нужен `Thread`, если уже 2020 год на дворе, и есть `Task` и `async/await`?

Comment: Хорошо. Теперь как формы заставить работать одновременно независимо от друг друга, чтобы таймер работал и на той и на другой форме одновременно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так
[image: пример работы]

В главной форме код такой

```
private void MenuItemNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form = new FormChild();
    form.MdiParent = this;
    //запускаем таймер и запросы к API
    form.Run();
    //отображаем окно
    form.Show();
}
```

В дочерней такой

```
public partial class FormChild : Form
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler _uiScheduler;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public FormChild()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //запоминаем синхр.контекст
        _uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        //настройка клиента
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com");
        _httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
        //настройка таймера
        _timer.Interval = 2000;
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Запуск Таймера
    /// </summary>
    public void Run()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Тик таймера
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //запускаем запрос к сайту и отображение результатов
        Task.Run(async () => await GetAnswer()).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            _richTextBox.Text += t.Result;
        }, _uiScheduler);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Запрос к сайту API
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<string> GetAnswer()
    {
        string result = String.Empty;

        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("posts/1");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            result = BuildOutput(json);
        }
        else
        {
            result = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Парсинг ответа
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="json"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string BuildOutput(string json)
    {
        dynamic blogPost = JObject.Parse(json);

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.AppendLine(new string('>', 45));
        builder.AppendLine($"[{ DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()}]");
        builder.AppendLine($"Пользователь: {blogPost.userId}");
        builder.AppendLine($"Заголовок:{blogPost.title}");
        builder.AppendLine(new string('<', 45));
        builder.AppendLine();

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Решение проекта целиком [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WindowsFormsTimerPosts).